# How to push a notification with schedule time on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, notifications

I want to push a notification such as "Hello new week" on the first day of each week.

And it run automatically each week.

I have referenced NotificationsDemo by import this project from Blackberry JDE Plugin.

```
public final class NotificationsDemo extends UiApplication
{    
    // com.rim.samples.device.notificationsdemo.NOTIFICATIONS_ID_1
    static final long NOTIFICATIONS_ID_1 = 0xdc5bf2f81374095L; 

    /**
     * Entry point for application.
     * @param args Command-line arguments
     */
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        if( args.length > 0 && args[ 0 ].equals( "autostartup" ) )
        {
            NotificationsDemo nd = new NotificationsDemo();
            nd.registerNotificationObjects();

            // Keep this instance around for rendering
            // Notification dialogs.
            nd.enterEventDispatcher(); 
        }
        else
        {
            // Start a new app instance for GUI operations.
            new NotificationsDemo().showGui();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the NotificationDemoScreen.
     */
    private void showGui()
    {
        // Create a new instance of the application and make the currently
        // running thread the application's event dispatch thread.
        pushScreen( new NotificationsDemoScreen() );
        enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    /**
     * Registers this application as the notification manager.
     */
    private void registerNotificationObjects()
    {
        // A source is registered to tell the system that our application will
        // be sending notification events.  This will will cause a new user
        // editable configuration to be added to the Profiles application. 
        NotificationsManager.registerSource( NOTIFICATIONS_ID_1, new Object()
        {
            public String toString()
            {
                return "Notifications Demo";
            }
        }, NotificationsConstants.IMPORTANT );

        // Our NotificationsEngineListener implementation will display a dialog
        // to the user when a deferred event is triggered.
        NotificationsManager.registerNotificationsEngineListener( NOTIFICATIONS_ID_1,
                new NotificationsEngineListenerImpl( this ) );        

        // Our Consequence implementation will invoked whenever an immediate
        // event occurs.        
        NotificationsManager.registerConsequence(ConsequenceImpl.ID, new ConsequenceImpl());
    }

    /**
     * The MainScreen class for our UiApplication. 
     */
    private static class NotificationsDemoScreen extends MainScreen
    {
        private long _eventId;

        // Constructor
        private  NotificationsDemoScreen()
        {
            // Initialize UI components.            
            setTitle( "Notifications Demo" );
            add( new RichTextField( "Trigger notification from menu." ) );

             //A menu item to generate immediate and deferred events.
            MenuItem notifyItem = new MenuItem( new StringProvider( "Notify (ID1)" ), 0x230010, 0 );
            notifyItem.setCommand(new Command(new CommandHandler() 
            {
                /**
                 * @see net.rim.device.api.command.CommandHandler#execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata, Object)
                 */
                public void execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata metadata, Object context) 
                {
                    int trigger = NotificationsConstants.MANUAL_TRIGGER;

                    // The timeout parameter is IGNORED unless the TRIGGER
                    // is OUT_OF_HOLSTER_TRIGGER.
                    long timeout = -1;

                    Event e = new Event( NotificationsDemo.NOTIFICATIONS_ID_1, _eventId, 500, timeout,
                            trigger );
                    _eventId++;
                    e.fire();
                }
            }));
            addMenuItem( notifyItem );


        }
    }
}
```

Follow the code we use menu to turn on LED but I want run without menu. I will auto run.

How do I set the time correctly to push my notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run an alternate entry point which will run a thread and that thread will check the beginning of each week and then display a dialog by using this method:

```
private void showMessage(String data) {
  UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
  Screen screen = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK, data, Dialog.OK,
    Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.EXCLAMATION),
    Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
  ui.queueStatus(screen, 1, true);
}
```

Comment: @ Farid Farhat:  I did what you mentionded and it display OK. But I can check the time forever and dialog always appear on the first day of the week. I only check at current time, if it is Monday is Dialog display and it is not Monday ( ex Sunday ), Dialog does not display  tomorrow.  Can you give me tips to resovle this problem

Comment: @Farid Farhat i had used timer there and used this method like this     `uiApplication.getUiApplication.invokeLater(new runnable(){run(){showmessage ("something")}});` but getting **illegal State of exception** do you know any other work around

Comment: Illegal state exceptions appear when you try to draw or access the UI components from outside the event Thread. invokeLater must resolve this for you. What is the message of the error you are getting? Maybe I can help with it